# REDIS sorted set sort time into two types

Tags: redis

REDIS 4.0.8

I would like to sort the following data by `createDate` and `endDate`:

```
info.item:*

    field : createDate , endDate , Name 
 createDate is now time to NumericTime
 endDate is A randomly set date at after now
 Name is anything
```

and I set info.item:* in item_List:

```
zadd item_List endDate info.item:*
if  createDate is 2018-03-06 to Numeric of info.item:1
       endDate is 2018-03-07 to Numeric
```

(Next time , Skip 'to Numeric')

```
    createDate is 2018-03-08  of info.item:2 
       endDate is 2018-03-12 

    createDate is 2018-03-09  of info.item:3 
       endDate is 2018-03-10 

    createDate is 2018-03-10  of info.item:4
       endDate is 2018-03-22
```

when using `zrangebyscore`

```
zrangebyscore endtime_Bucket 2018-03-08 +inf
i got 
info.item:3
info.item:2
info.item:4
```

the result is correct.

Additionally, I want to sort by `createDate` when the `endDate` is later than now

I expect this result:

```
info.item:4
info.item:3
info.item:2
```

but failed.

I tried sort commands:

```
sort item_List by *->createDate desc
```

result:

```
info.item:4
info.item:3
info.item:2
info.item:1
```

How can I exclude items when the `endDate` is older than now and sort by `createDate`?

now is 2018-03-08

Answer (score 1):

1. Redis sorted set score is 64 bit float, and supports 53 bit of integer range.
   `-(2^53) to +(2^53)` ( both inclusive ) Or -9007199254740992 and 9007199254740992
2. This allows as to mask both createDate & endDate in the score. 
   A performance optimized approach is to have all bits of the score set to zero, and use left 25 bits for createDate, and right 25 bits for endDate of the 53 integer bits. In this case both createDate & endDate would be unixtimestamp of the beginning of the date.
3. A simpler approach would be to use string concatenation of dates and their conversion to numbers.
   Example:

   ```
   >>> endDate = "20180308"
   >>> createDate = "20180305"
   >>> endDate+createDate
   '2018030820180305'
   >>> int(endDate+createDate) < 9007199254740992
   True
   ```

Both createDate & endDates appended together and converted to number are smaller than the integer value redis sorted set score, and we can use this to our advantage.

4. To find items greater than endDate older than now, i.e. todays date, you can use `ZRANGEBYSCORE` with score min = 2018030800000000   ( you can also use a max score to have a endDate range instead of just older than)
   . This result would be sorted by right part of the score, which is createDate represented as an integer.

This approach will only work for YYYY/MM/DD or DD/MM/YYYY format of dates, as their string based lexographical sort & numeric represenation sort yield the same result. This will fail for American date formats like MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: `(2018050120180309 data1) ,(2018091020180307 data2),(2018040120180308 data3) , (2018030620180301 data4)  in List ` can i exclude sorted by createDate?   i tried this solution 
`result : data3    createDate : 20180308
            data1                         20180309 
            data2                         20180307`

i want  2 , 3 , 1 
Do I need to sort again after receiving the results?